# Cannot offset path in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cc-2017

[image: Where it says type (see pic), I need it to say path]

I am trying to offset a path and it is not working.  I believe my problem lies where it says "type".

Comment: Are you trying to offset your path using Object > Path > Offset path or something different?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a mistake. Look at your image, the top left info is about character and paragraph, this never appears when a shape is selected.

Here two apparent equal paths:

[image: paths]

When the green is selected, the top left indicates this is a **Rectangle**.

[image: rectangle]

When the red is selected, the top left indicates **Type**, because is a **Text Frame**. If you touch a shape with the **Text Tool** immediately is converted to a **Text Frame**. That's why you can not do some modifications.

[image: textframe]

To make changes to a Text Frame Path, select it with the **Direct Selection Tool**, the white pointer.

[image: path]

Comment: ok got it.  i knew there was a simple solution.  i spend 'so much' time trying to figure it out.  thank you!